# addEventListener('storage', func) Firefox private window does not work

Tags: firefox, local-storage, firefox-addon, addeventlistener, incognito-mode

In the Firefox browser in a private window, when changing storage, the Listener does not work.

Everything works in a normal browser.

```
const changeStatusListener = () => {
    console.log('change');
  };
window.addEventListener('storage', changeStatusListener);
```

But with other events, such as a click, everything works.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Rojo no errors